# Sharepoint Wiki Link name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible in the Wiki to have a link name, but different file name.

For example, [[Canada]]   would link to Canada_a_NicePlace.aspx without having to create a http:// link?

I'm looking for a solution for non-techies to have short links to big filenames.

Comment: I spotted this feature only when I renamed a file on my wiki, and it editied all the links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[Canada_a_NicePlace|Canada]]